# WIMP theme not found - only when bundling with PyInstaller (Windows)

Tags: python, pygtk, pyinstaller

I have built a simple application using Glade and PyGTK (on Windows 7). From Python interpreter everything looks fine. However, after bundling with PyInstaller, I get this warning:

```
 GtkWarning: Could not find the icon 'gtk-missing-image'. The 'hicolor' theme was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
```

And the GUI looks ugly...

Here's the screenshot of both runs.

[image: screenshot]

### EDIT

I found the 'hicolor' theme files in GTK installation. It appears to contain only icons. Therefore, it's not the cause for the general look, but only for the different icons that can be seem in the title bars.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem, based on http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/14

However, their solution didn't work for me as-is, so I modified it a little.

Add this to the `spec` file:

```
a.datas += [('gtkrc', r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\runtime\share\themes\MS-Windows\gtk-2.0\gtkrc', 'DATA')]
a.binaries += [(r'lib\gtk-2.0\2.10.0\engines\libwimp.dll', r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\runtime\lib\gtk-2.0\2.10.0\engines\libwimp.dll', 'BINARY') ]
```

And this to `__init__`:

```
gtk.rc_add_default_file(resource_path("gtkrc"))
```

Now it looks good... (BTW, It didn't solve the original warning regarding the missing icon and 'hicolor' theme, but this is of less importance.)